# Blender weird line going through model

Tags: modeling, rendering, rigging

So I've been working on this project for about two days and I don't know if this issue was there from the beginning but I think I would have noticed before. I am nearing the completition of my project but I have just realised that I have a strange line going through my model from top to bottom. There is a linked image of the issue.
Does anyone have any clue what could be causing that?
Thanks in advance for your answers[image: model 3D issue]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Perhaps and edge that you can delete. Or share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok so turns out it is caused by the wireframe modifier having a thickness to high if that can help someone in the same scenario!